# Create an animation with Python3 and Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I tried to create an animation with `matplotlib.pyplot` and `matplotlib.animation` and I encountured two problems:

- 1st is that, I went to [matplotlib animation page](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image2.html) and then I tried their code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
ims = []
for i in range(60):
    x += np.pi / 15.
    y += np.pi / 20.
    im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

# ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')

plt.show()
```

I got an error: AttributeError: 'function' has no attribute 'canvas' (I re-tried and I didn't get any error...

- 2nd, when I uncomment `ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')` I get this error: TypeError: 'MovieWriterRegistry' object is not an iterator. This one bothers me a lot more. If you have any solution about this last problem, please let me now.

WolfGang1710.

Comment: Please repeat [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the intro tour.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the documentation of the method [`Animation.save`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save) the default writer is 'ffmpeg'. Therefore, you need to have ffmpeg installed for it to work.

Comment: I did this but the problem is still here unfortunately. Thank you anyway!